# Recursive helper function throws component.get is not a function

Tags: lightning-aura-components, recursion

I have a recursive helper function that checks every 5 seconds for the status of a queueable job.

Upon the first recursive call, the helper method throws
`Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [component.get is not a function]`

The helper function:

```
checkUploadStatus: function(component, event, helper, jobId, cdId) {
    let action = component.get('c.checkUploadJobStatus');
    action.setParams({'jobId': jobId, 'cdId': cdId});
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        let state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            let returnVal = response.getReturnValue();
            console.log('returnVal', returnVal);
            if (returnVal === null) {
                window.setTimeout(
                    $A.getCallback(helper.checkUploadStatus.bind(component, helper, jobId, cdId)),
                    5000
                );
            } else {
                // do work
            }
        } else {
            // handle error
        }
    })
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

How come `component` is not recognized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply move it to callback logic, no need to bind, arrow functions make `this` easier.

```
action.setCallback(this, (response) => {
            if (response.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
                    setTimeout(
                        $A.getCallback(() => {
                            this.checkUploadStatus(comp, event, helper);
                        }),1);
            }
        });
```

Notice two changes,

1. `setCallback` to arrow function so this inside still refers to helper.
2. `getCallback`, bind to a comparatively simpler call with arrow functions.

Comment: thanks! i actually didn't notice the first change, so i only changed the setTimeout's function to arrow function and it worked. what does using arrow functions do exactly instead of a regular `function(reponse) {}`?

Comment: You can use `this` instead of writing `helper` everytime in the callback. The way i used `this` to call `checkUploadStatus` instead of `helper` :) If you use arrow fn in callback.

Answer (score 0):

The first element to bind sets the `this` context:

```
$A.getCallback(helper.checkUploadStatus.bind(this, component, helper, jobId, cdId);
```

Since the first parameter was the component, it became `this`, and your helper became component, etc.